# How to log to a file with org.apache.commons.logging?

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons

This may be obvious, but I have been looking for a simple example of using `org.apache.commons.logging` to log to a specific file (i.e. `/path/to/my-log.txt`)

```
public class MyClass {

    static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // What to do here to get log to output to a file???

        log.info("I want to appear in a specific log file")
    }

}
```

Comment: This is just spitballing, but maybe set up a logger for a dummy class, and do `static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ThatOtherClass.class);`

Comment: I'm trying to write the output to a file that I can specify. So, that message inside log.info will appear inside a specific file (i.e. /path/to/my-log.txt)

Comment: When you say specify, do you mean specify dynamically from within the program?

Comment: At this point all I am concerned about is hard-coding it into the above example. I just want to be able to specify String myfile="/path/to/file.txt" and then set myfile as the target for log output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on logging implementation that you have in your project. If you do not have log4j on the classpath, commons-logging default to java.util.logging. In this case you need to configure java.util.logging.FileHander. You can do it thru logging.properties file or programmatically

```
    Logger.getGlobal().addHandler(new FileHandler("log"));
    LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class).info("/path/to/mylog.log");
```

Answer (score 2):

Commons-Logging is just a logging facade, you should use Log4j or JDK-Logging do the real logging tasks, which you can set the log file.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/
or
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

it's configuration file will like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, R
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.File=/path/to/mylog.log
```

Comment: How would I do that inside the code? Let's say I'm passing an argument for the user running the jar to specific their own log file. How would I say in the above code sample that log output should to go "/path/to/mylog.log"? Is there some way to specify a log file handler?

I know in python this is very straightforward. Is it not so simple in Java?